# How to install DroidCam PC Client for Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, tar, droidcam

I'm trying to install DroidCam PC client in my Ubuntu 20.04 but I'm not able to do so. The linux headers are installed, and the zip file too is installed but I'm not able to unzip it. Either this:

````
tar: invalid option -- '[some image type of thing]'
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.``` or this: ```bzip2:(stdin) is not a bzip2 file.
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Erroe is not recoverable: exiting now
````

The commands I've given are:

1. `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
2. `sudo wget https://www.dev47apps.com/files/600/droidcam-64bit.tar.bz2 -O droidcam.tar.bz2`
3. `sudo tar –xjvf droidcam.tar.bz2 [unsuccessful]`

   ***Somebody who knows how to handle with this, please answer.*** **I've checked with the developer website and the information provided isn't clear enough [ https://www.dev47apps.com/droidcam/linuxx/ ]**  I've previously installed the software in the same PC but for 18.04. After the upgrade everything was lost. The website I reffered for the commands mentioned above is https://www.click4infos.com/droidcam/ .

Answer (score 1):

Droidcam website currently shows a different list of commands: the archive is not a .tar but a .zip file.
Have you tried to repeat the sequence?

The following sequence is copy-pasted from https://www.dev47apps.com/droidcam/linuxx/

**Note**: Only 64-bit binaries are provided, you’ll need to compile the client from source if you are running a 32-bit system.

1. Ensure the following dependencies are installed (using apt-get, yum, etc.): `gcc make linux-headers-$(uname -r)`
2. If `droidcam` is already installed, make sure it’s not open.
3. Get the latest client:

```
    cd /tmp/
    wget https://files.dev47apps.net/linux/droidcam_latest.zip
    echo "952d57a48f991921fc424ca29c8e3d09 droidcam_latest.zip" | md5sum -c --
    #OK?
    unzip droidcam_latest.zip -d droidcam && cd droidcam
    sudo ./install
```